# TFS 2017 web access - how to add saved query to Work menu?

Tags: tfs

We have TFS 2017 on-premise, and I'd like to add a saved query to my team's `Work` menu.

[image: I'd like the query to appear here]

Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do that. You could, in theory, write an extension.

An easier option is to pin queries to the team's dashboard. There are [several widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=vsts#query-results-widget) for visualizing work item query results.

Comment: Thanks. Annoying the menus aren't customisable in this way though.